# How to fetch all web pages from under a directory in JCR using CURL in CQ?

Tags: curl, aem, jcr

I want to fetch all web pages(recursively) from under a directory in my CQ content using curl. Can someone please help?

Comment: curl isn't a browser, or a spider engine. if you want to fetch multiple things, you'll have to call curl multiple times.

Comment: Wget might be the solution for you. It can fetch html recursively. 
My question is: Do you want to access the pages as html via http or can you get them via the filesystem?

Comment: I want to fetch a particular node in each page, modify a certain property of it and write back to the content. I have too many pages, so, running curl multiple times is not an option. Right now, I am testing on my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Sling JSON GET servlet is enabled by default in CQ so provided access control allows it you can retrieve subtrees with URLs like `/content.tidy.N.json` where N is the desired recursion level.

As an example,

```
curl -s -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/content/geometrixx.tidy.2.json
```

Retrieves two levels of the tree under `/content/geometrixx`.

If the result contains more elements than a configurable limit you'll get a 302 response that lists the URLs that provide the result in multiple smaller units.

See also http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html

Comment: Hi @Bertrand, I used the following curl command to retrieve JSON from my localhost and it worked fine (the subtree has just 5 pages)

curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/the-path-to-the-subtree.tidy.infinity.json


However, when I tried running the curl command on the production server (subtree has 8400 pages), it gives me a strange output like this:

["/the-path-to-the-subtree.tidy.0.json"]

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That's what I meant above by "a 302 response that lists the URLs that provide the result in multiple smaller units", in that case you need to request those .N.json URLs to get the details.

Comment: When I do .0.json and .1.json, I get the right output. The actual json I want is in the next level. .2.json gives [.0.json] as the output. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I found a workaround. I tweaked my code to call .infinity.json for each of the keys in .1.json. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah yes right, I forgot about the required depth selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/bin/querybuilder` servlet. For instance, following command will fetch all `cq:Page` nodes from the `/content/geometrixx/en`:

```
curl -u admin:admin \
     "http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?p.limit=-1&path=%2fcontent%2fgeometrixx%2fen&type=cq%3aPage"
```

The URL itself may not be very clear, but it can be generated automatically. In order to get such URL, open the QueryBuilder Debugger tool available under `/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html`. Then paste following QueryBuilder predicates:

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/geometrixx/en
p.limit=-1
```

and click search. Generated URL to the JSON results is available under *JSON QueryBuilder link*. More info on the predicates format can be found in the [official documentation](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html).